# How to use generics in Typescript and React to define component prop value by another component prop value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a reusable function React component.

I want to be able to define a component type and I would like for TS to infer the type of options my React component would be accepting.

Here are my possible input types:

```
type InputType =
| 'text'
| 'select'
| 'radioGroup'
| 'checkboxGroup'
| 'textarea';
```

This is the interface for my functional React component:

```
interface Input<TInput extends InputType>
{
...other props that are not important
type: TInput;
options?: // This has to be a different type based on the passed TInput.
}
```

Further below in component code, I do conditional rendering with

```
...
if(type === "checkbox") {
return <Checkbox
options={options}
...other props
/>
}
...
```

I imagined the usage as such:

```
...
<Input type="text" options={selectOptionsVariable} />
<Input type="upload" />
<Input type="checkbox" options={checkboxOptionsVariable} />
...
```

I tried multiple ways of mapping the passed TInput to a pre-existing type such as:

```
type InputOptionsMapping = {
text: Array<SelectOption>;
select: Array<SelectOption>;
radioGroup: Array<RadioOption>;
checkboxGroup: Array<CheckboxOption>;
textarea: never;
};
```

but even if I define the type on the interface such that:

```
interface Input<TInput extends InputType>
{
...other props that are not important
type: InputOptionsMapping[TInput];
options?: // TS compiler still infers options as a union of all possible values       
of InputOptionsMapping i.e. "Array<SelectOption> | Array<RadioGroupOptions>   
etc...
}
```

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is this:

If passed TInput is "text" or "select", options type would be inferred as Array.
If passed TInput is "radio", options type would be inferred as Array.
If passed TInput is "checkbox", options type would be inferred as Array.
If passed TInput is "textarea", no options would be passed to the component.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can anyone point me to the right direction here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
import React from 'react'

interface TextType {
    type: 'text'
    options: {
        test: string
    }
}

interface SelectType {
    type: 'select'
    options: {
        data: string[]
    }
}

type AllowedTypes = TextType | SelectType

const Input = (props: AllowedTypes) => <input />

const _ = <Input type='text' options={{ test: '' }} /> // ok
const __ = <Input type='text' options={{ data: [''] }} /> // expected error
```

PLease see `AllowedTypes` it is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). THis is what you are looking for. THe most important thing here is a `discriminator` which in this case is a shared `type` property. Each element in the union should contain this property which should have a different value.

In the last (error) example, Input is highlighted. It is ok, however we can do better, we can highlight exact invalid prop instead of the whole component:

```js
const Input = <
    Type extends string,
    Options extends Extract<AllowedTypes, { type: Type }>['options'],
>(props: { type: Type, options: Options }) => <input />

const _ = <Input type='text' options={{ test: '' }} /> // ok
const __ = <Input type='text' options={{ data: [''] }} /> // expected error
```

[PLayground](https://tsplay.dev/mZVQ1m)